# How to get the first entirely visible element within an element that has horizontal scrolling using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I need to get the first element that is entirely visible within a scrollable DIV using jQuery. I'm close, but something isn't right.

Can anyone spot the problem?

```
$('div').on('scroll', function () {
  var cutoff = $(this).scrollLeft();

  $('li').removeClass('firstVisible').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.offset().left > cutoff) {
      $this.addClass('firstVisible');

      return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on the screen
    }
  });

  console.log($('li.firstVisible').index());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/axwR7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this.offset()` will return position relative to document (not to div with scrolling), so to check visibility you need to compare it to div position (not scroll left)

```
$('div').on('scroll', function () {
var cutoff = $(this).offset().left;

$('li').removeClass('firstVisible').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.offset().left >= cutoff) {
        $this.addClass('firstVisible');

        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on the screen
    }
});
```

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/axwR7/2/